# I can't update data realtime

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>



<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<script type="text/javascript">
function repeatAjax(){
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'getdata.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(resp) {

                    $('#name').html(resp[0]);


          },
          complete: function() {
                setTimeout(repeatAjax,500); 
             }
        });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <center>
                        <h1>List</h1>

            <div id="name" name="name"></div>  

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

and this result no show anything

http://s1.postimg.org/hd8p7ecoe/listdoctorshow.jpg

and this my getdata.php

```
<?php
mysql_query("SET NAMEs UTF8"); 
    $objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("SET NAMEs UTF8"); 
    $objDB = mysql_select_db("member");
    $strSQL = "    SELECT * FROM mem2 order by date limit 1,1";
    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL) or die (mysql_error());
    $intNumField = mysql_num_fields($objQuery);
    $result = array();
    $arrCol = array();


    while($obResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
    {

        for($i=0;$i<$intNumField;$i++)
        {
            $arrCol[mysql_field_name($objQuery,$i)] = $obResult[$i]; 
        }
        array_push($result,$arrCol);
    }


    $response = json_encode($result);
    echo json_encode($result);

mysql_close($objConnect);
?>
```

and this result

http://s17.postimg.org/75io9xg8d/showgetdata.jpg

i don't know what i do anything wrong

Thankyou

Comment: `resp[0]` is the array according to your imagure. What you actually want is `resp[0]["id1"];`

Answer (score 1):

No need to make it more complicated, in your PHP:

```
$response = json_encode($result);
echo json_encode($result);

// this doesn't make sense
```

Just loop them and push them inside normally.

```
$result = array();
while($obResult = mysql_fetch_assoc($objQuery)){
    $result[] = $obResult;
}

echo json_encode($result);
exit;
```

In your JS, loop the response first:

```
success: function(response) {

    var results = '';
    $.each(response, function(index, element){
        // build the markup first, don't feed the response into .html() directly
        results += '<p>' + element.id1 + '</p>';
        results += '<p>' + element.name1 + '</p>';
        results += '<p>' + element.date + '</p>';
    });    

    $('#name').html(results); // after the markup is complete, then use this
},
```

Note: Use the improved extension which is mysqli or use PDO instead.

Comment: Up-voted because you're pointing out how overly complex the OP has his current php script at and offering a simple (more viable) solution!

Comment: @Darren yeah its was kind of odd having to fetch the rows and then looping the fields and using encode twice

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function repeatAjax(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'getdata.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(resp) {
          $('#name').html(resp[0]);
      }
    });
}

setInterval(repeatAjax,500);
```

Hope this helped. If you're still not getting anything back try console logging `resp` and see if you are indeed getting some response from your php file.

Comment: Thank You for answer now i delete complete function and add setinterval that your suggestion and it's work